# AutoFixture - Exclude a particular enum entry

Tags: c#, enums, autofixture

Given an enum:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    DoNotInclude, 

    IncludeThis, 

    IncludeThisToo
}
```

and a class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyEnum MyEnum { get; set; }
}
```

and a test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyTest()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();

    var myClasses = fixture.CreateMany<MyClass>(4);
}
```

`myClasses` now contains one of each of the `MyEnum` values

I want it to exclude the `DoNotInclude` value.

I know how to `.Customize<>()` using `.With()` to force it to use a specific value for each instance but cannot find an obvious option to use all except one value.

e.g.:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyTest()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();

    var myClasses = new List<MyClass>();

    fixture.Customize<MyClass>(c => c.With(x => x.MyEnum, MyEnum.IncludeThis));

    myClasses.AddRange(fixture.CreateMany<MyClass>(2));

    fixture.Customize<MyClass>(c => c.With(x => x.MyEnum, MyEnum.IncludeThisToo));

    myClasses.AddRange(fixture.CreateMany<MyClass>(2));
}
```

How do I do this with a single `.CreateMany`?

EDIT: Following the answer from the question this is a duplicate of, here is my solution based on creating classes with enum properties:

```
var myClasses = fixture.Create<Generator<MyClass>>().Where(c => c.MyEnum != MyEnum.DoNotInclude).Take(4);
```